# Flutter giving error when running project saying something nullok error and also the dependency itself has error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Please tell how to solve this nullok error problem with flutter_svg error

Answer (score 0):

As I am running a project made in 1.22.5 which doesn't have null safety and 2.2 has null safety I just needed to roll back the version to 1.22.5 to get rid of the this nullok Error

Thank you :)